# sudo auth session while executing command using NSTask in cocoa application

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sudo

I have an application that requires executing a command with sudo. How can I ask for a password and if successful, then run the sudo command using NSTask.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to give permission using NSTask - objective-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541654/how-to-give-permission-using-nstask-objective-c)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question. This question is about *actually using sudo* (though I agree that the correct answer is “use Authorization Services instead”).

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a more lightweight solution, there is another way.  I wrote this generic implementation which should achieve what you want:

```
- (BOOL) runProcessAsAdministrator:(NSString*)scriptPath
                     withArguments:(NSArray *)arguments
                            output:(NSString **)output
                  errorDescription:(NSString **)errorDescription {

    NSString * allArgs = [arguments componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
    NSString * fullScript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", scriptPath, allArgs];

    NSDictionary *errorInfo = [NSDictionary new];
    NSString *script =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"do shell script \"%@\" with administrator privileges", fullScript];

    NSAppleScript *appleScript = [[NSAppleScript new] initWithSource:script];
    NSAppleEventDescriptor * eventResult = [appleScript executeAndReturnError:&errorInfo];

    // Check errorInfo
    if (! eventResult)
    {
        // Describe common errors
        *errorDescription = nil;
        if ([errorInfo valueForKey:NSAppleScriptErrorNumber])
        {
            NSNumber * errorNumber = (NSNumber *)[errorInfo valueForKey:NSAppleScriptErrorNumber];
            if ([errorNumber intValue] == -128)
                *errorDescription = @"The administrator password is required to do this.";
        }

        // Set error message from provided message
        if (*errorDescription == nil)
        {
            if ([errorInfo valueForKey:NSAppleScriptErrorMessage])
                *errorDescription =  (NSString *)[errorInfo valueForKey:NSAppleScriptErrorMessage];
        }

        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        // Set output to the AppleScript's output
        *output = [eventResult stringValue];

        return YES;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
    NSString * output = nil;
    NSString * processErrorDescription = nil;
    BOOL success = [self runProcessAsAdministrator:@"/usr/bin/id"
                    withArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-un", nil]
                           output:&output
                            errorDescription:&processErrorDescription
                  asAdministrator:YES];


    if (!success) // Process failed to run
    {
         // ...look at errorDescription 
    }
    else
    {
         // ...process output
    }
```

Hat tip to [user950473](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841937/authorizationexecutewithprivileges-is-deprecated).

Answer (score 1):

Use the Authorization Services, Luke. (If you've ever seen the "Application XYZ needs an admin password to continue", this is how it's implemented. It does **not** use sudo under the sheets.)

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html