# AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges is deprecated

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

Since updating to OSX 10.7 Lion, Xcode tells me that `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges` is deprecated.

Can anyone suggest a way my application can write to a directory it doesn't have permission for?

Answer (score 37):

In fact, `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges()` has been deprecated for a very long time, it's only recently that the header file has caught up with this fact.

You can create a privileged helper tool as part of your application. You can use `ServiceManagement.framework`'s `SMJobBless()` function to have the helper deployed into the system `launchd` context: then when you need to perform privileged tasks, you just message the privileged helper to do that work.

There's a little bit of hidden complexity, in that the app and the helper must each declare the signing identity of the other before `SMJobBless()` believes they're supposed to be used together, and you need to get the linker to write the helper tool's `Info.plist` file into the binary. That's all covered by [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ServiceManagement/Reference/ServiceManagement_header_reference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SMJobBless) and Apple have provided [a sample project](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SMJobBless/), too.

I [wrote an example application](https://github.com/iamleeg/LogViewer) that uses `SMJobBless()` to deploy its privileged helper.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. If AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges() has been deprecated for a long time, should it still continue to work? Basically, this stopped working in my application since the Lion update, and I assumed it was because it is now being marked as deprecated... Should it infact still work, and my problem lies elsewhere? Many thanks

Comment: You shouldn't be relying on `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges()`, it's a horrendous security hole. The way to do what you want to do is with `SMJobBless()`.

Comment: @GrahamLee And what about using `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges` for the installer? Reference says that "You should use this function only to allow installers to run as root and to allow a setuid tool to repair its setuid bit if lost" and Authorization Services Programming Guide suggests to use this function to launch installers (although it somewhat outdated). Is there any alternative to launch installer in simple application like command line tool?

Comment: That's out of date, too. If you're using System Management you can deploy the privileged components without an installer.

Comment: @GrahamLee. Well ok, and what if I have a pkg file and I want to launch `installer` utility on it? How can I do that without using deprecated functionality. Can I use system utilities as helper tool? I understand that I can launch installer with NSWorkspace class. But I don't need a GUI installer app, I want to do it quietly and I need an install process exit code, so I need to wait for it. What can you suggest in such case?

Comment: @cody hopefully you've found a solution in the past six years, but for the record—I was able to run `installer` as `root` from a privileged helper tool using `posix_spawn`

Comment: Would this work on BigSur (macOS 11.6)? Otherwise how to get admin permission? I'm trying to write an app Uninstaller which uses `NSFileManager` to delete `/Applications/MyApplication.app` folder and some app data in `~/Library/Application Support/my.app/`

Comment: @user23743 what's insecure about `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges()`? And the reference docs for `SMJobBless()` say that it's deprecated now, too :( What's the replacement in 2022? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/servicemanagement/1431078-smjobbless

Answer (score 37):

I know it sounds crazy, but this *actually works*:

```
NSDictionary *error = [NSDictionary new]; 
NSString *script =  @"do shell script \"whoami > /tmp/me\" with administrator privileges";  
NSAppleScript *appleScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:script]; 
if ([appleScript executeAndReturnError:&error]) {
  NSLog(@"success!"); 
} else {
  NSLog(@"failure!"); 
}
```

I'm executing an Applescript from Objective C. The only disadvantage is that you cannot gain permanent root privileges with this. It will ask for the password each time you run this.

Comment: Would ya look at that.  so YOU'RE `root`?!  Oh wait, I am.  No, wait..  _AppleScript is_?  Jesus.  That is certainly crazy.   The only thing that would be crazier is if it didn't ask for your password, lol.

Comment: I attempted to use this but it didn't ask me for my password ever. Instead it just skipped to printing "failure!" When I printed the description of error, I got this: "NSAppleScriptErrorMessage = "The administrator user name or password was incorrect.";"

This is in an app with the sandbox enabled... does anyone have suggestions that work with a sandbox enabled app?

Comment: FYI: As documented in Technical Note TN2065: do shell script in AppleScript (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2065/_index.html):

Use the administrator privileges, user name and password parameters like this:

do shell script "command" user name "me" password "mypassword" with administrator privileges

Comment: Note, that Threading Programming Guide says that NSAppleScript class must be used only from the main thread of an application. Although I myself using it not only in the main thread and have no problems.

Comment: I am getting DYLD_ environment variables being ignored because main executable (/usr/libexec/security_authtrampoline) is setuid or setgid on 10.8

Comment: You can gain permanent root privileges if you a) create a separate binary that will do what you want as root, b) copy that binary to a safe writable location (e.g. /Library/Application Support/xxx), c) set the setuid bit on that binary, d) chown the binary as root, and e) chmod the binary appropriately. Maybe I'll create an example project on Github one day...

Comment: I don't know why you and others are surprised. AppleScript is designed to be standalone, and maintain complex flows and scenarios. So it makes things easy (and NOT less secure). It does NOT run as root, and you don't need "root" for copying files to anywhere - you just need the "Full Disk Access" capability. Plus - administrator privileges are NOT root. Macs can run root-less and still copy files anywhere. It's probably the easiest thing to do programmatically, but not a fast or preferable solution.

Comment: The AppleScript approach no longer seems to work on macOS 12. For example: `% osascript -e 'do shell script "/bin/sh ./hello.sh" with administrator privileges'` errors with the following message:  `0:82: execution error: /bin/sh: ./hello.sh: Operation not permitted (126)`. However the same command runs successfully if the `with administrator privileges` portion is omitted from AppleScript. (P.S. The script hello.sh has required r/w/x permissions, etc.)

Answer (score 18):

Based on a great find by user950473 I've implemented his/her discovery as a method; thought I'd share the code in case it's helpful.

```
- (BOOL) runProcessAsAdministrator:(NSString*)scriptPath
                     withArguments:(NSArray *)arguments
                            output:(NSString **)output
                  errorDescription:(NSString **)errorDescription {

    NSString * allArgs = [arguments componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
    NSString * fullScript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"'%@' %@", scriptPath, allArgs];

    NSDictionary *errorInfo = [NSDictionary new];
    NSString *script =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"do shell script \"%@\" with administrator privileges", fullScript];

    NSAppleScript *appleScript = [[NSAppleScript new] initWithSource:script];
    NSAppleEventDescriptor * eventResult = [appleScript executeAndReturnError:&errorInfo];

    // Check errorInfo
    if (! eventResult)
    {
        // Describe common errors
        *errorDescription = nil;
        if ([errorInfo valueForKey:NSAppleScriptErrorNumber])
        {
            NSNumber * errorNumber = (NSNumber *)[errorInfo valueForKey:NSAppleScriptErrorNumber];
            if ([errorNumber intValue] == -128)
                *errorDescription = @"The administrator password is required to do this.";
        }

        // Set error message from provided message
        if (*errorDescription == nil)
        {
            if ([errorInfo valueForKey:NSAppleScriptErrorMessage])
                *errorDescription =  (NSString *)[errorInfo valueForKey:NSAppleScriptErrorMessage];
        }

        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        // Set output to the AppleScript's output
        *output = [eventResult stringValue];

        return YES;
    }
}
```

Usage example:

```
    NSString * output = nil;
    NSString * processErrorDescription = nil;
    BOOL success = [self runProcessAsAdministrator:@"/usr/bin/id"
                         withArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-un", nil]
                         output:&output
                         errorDescription:&processErrorDescription];


    if (!success) // Process failed to run
    {
         // ...look at errorDescription 
    }
    else
    {
         // ...process output
    }
```

It's very slightly hacky, but IMHO is a satisfactory solution.

Comment: This method fails if there is a space in the path of the script, which is likely if you want to run a script included in your application bundle.  To fix this, just change the format when setting fullScript to @"'%@' %@" so the process path name is quoted.

Comment: Hi, is there a way to add the app icon in the password prompt in place of the blank file with your solution?

Comment: @Yann86 I don't believe so, as the prompt is delivered by Applescript itself

Answer (score 7):

*AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges is indeed deprecated*. 

But fortunately, there is a new recommended way to proceed.

As of 10.6 there is the new API and it is recommended to install a helper tool that will perform the privileged operation. Apple provide a [code sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SMJobBless/Introduction/Intro.html) that clearly demonstrate how to manage it.

*Make sure you check out their [readme.txt](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SMJobBless/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010071-ReadMe_txt-DontLinkElementID_3) since contrarily to other code sample there is more to do than just downloading the project and running it.*

**From The SMJobBless example introduction**

> **SMJobBless** demonstrates how to securely install a helper tool that performs a privileged operation and how to associate the tool
>   with an application that invokes it.
>
> As of Snow Leopard, this is the preferred method of managing privilege
>   escalation on Mac OS X and **should be used instead** of earlier
>   approaches such as **BetterAuthorizationSample** or directly calling
>   **AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges**.
>
> SMJobBless uses ServiceManagement.framework that was introduced in Mac
>   OS X v10.6 Snow Leopard.

Source: [Apple SMJobBless code sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SMJobBless/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: Why would you say that? I was able to download the sample code today, using the link I provided and a non-paid developer account.

Comment: Have you run a project successfully yet? It was asking for code signing of the app with an OSX developer account.