# Escalate App Privileges Programmatically OS X

Tags: c++, macos, root

I've done some digging and the main ideas I've seen floating around are using setuid/getuid and using the Authorization Services (which, for some reason gives me a symbol error when compiling but appears to be deprecated now).

My application needs to be able to request root access (for accessing a raw disk drive) at a certain point, preferably with the OS X authentication dialog (I'm new to OS X so I have no idea what to call that).

Answer (score 5):

Authorization Services is pretty well supported, AFAIK.

[Here's a link to a tutorial (with sample projects!)](https://github.com/michaelvobrien/OSXSimpleAuth/wiki) which you can use to launch a small tool in which you can get admin priviledges and then you can call the [`setpriority`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/setpriority.2.html) API on your calling process (documentation linked for you).

Comment: Thanks!  For some reason I can't find where AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges is declared as when I #include <security/authorization.h> I have symbols for pretty much everything else, except that one function

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Reference/authorization_ref/Reference/reference.html says that AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges  has been deprecated since 10.7. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841937/authorizationexecutewithprivileges-is-deprecated has some related info.

Comment: Whooops... `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges` became "deprecated" as of 10.7.  I'm looking at Apple's [Authorization Services Tasks](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/03authtasks/authtasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000995-CH206-TP9) documentation to see how you can [`renice`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/renice.8.html) the calling process.

Comment: @Vishal that's what I noticed as well, but I wasn't too sure why or whether or not it was bad to use it.  Thanks for linking to the related question!

Comment: Both links are dead

Comment: I just fixed them @CasperB.Hansen