# Qt: Make program ask for user elevation at execution(windows)

Tags: c++, security, qt

How do you set a program to ask for elevation upon execution? I've asked around here and there, but haven't gotten an answer. I'm not sure how I would do this, but the program that i want to write, needs permissions to be run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Security models are rather platform-specific.  Qt does not AFAIK address this sort of thing.  (Case in point: the Qt Creator installer itself choked when I didn't run it as root.)

You'll presumably need to make native calls or interact with some daemon designed for the purpose.  Often easiest to try whatever it is you think you should be able to do, and check for failure, and if you can't do what you want then ask the user to explicitly re-run with higher privileges.

**Linux:**

[Best way elevate the privileges programmatically under different versions of Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690463/best-way-elevate-the-privileges-programmatically-under-different-versions-of-lin)

**Windows:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163486.aspx

**Mac:**

[Escalate App Privileges Programmatically OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920771/escalate-app-privileges-programmatically-os-x)

*(Note: Often if you have to ask a question about something like this, there may be a better way to do whatever it is you're trying to do.  Consider posting a question that is more general about what you want, and you might get suggestions on a way to do it more cleanly.)*

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to ask to be elevated automatically.

The only way I can think of doing it would be to have a service running as a Local Administrator account and performing elevated run for you.

I have used this when installing/uninstalling MSI packages autmatically as part of a CI Build (Go Agent runs as Local System Account)