# In Swift Cocoa, how to ask for elevated permissions once and not need to ask again?

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, cocoa

I am trying to write an app that will edit a file that is stored in

```
/private/etc/hosts
```

Normally, from the Terminal, I must use `sudo` to write to this file, so I should think I need elevated permissions in my cocoa app.

I was hoping to ask for it once, and then somehow store the permission so I don't need to ask again. I am a little lost about where to start.

Comment: I have the same question. I want to run /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/nvram boot-args="-v" but get exception [General] Couldn't posix_spawn: error 1

Answer (score 1):

The normal way to do this is by using a helper program to make the required changes and then requesting administrator privileges when the helper is run.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8920771/escalate-app-privileges-programmatically-os-x) for some more information on requesting admin privileges.