# Mountain Lion and AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges warning

Tags: xcode, cocoa, dyld

I have updated my OSX and xCode now when I call AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges

I getting log message:

```
dyld: DYLD_ environment variables being ignored because main executable (/usr/libexec/security_authtrampoline) is setuid or setgid
```

what is that, can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, this very handy class https://github.com/sveinbjornt/STPrivilegedTask relies on the AEWP function and I cannot use it on ML... would be super cool to update it for ML!

Answer (score 0):

This problem is since 10.7. But in 10.8 they probably made changes that made this function not working as it should be. Anyway 2 possible solutions are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841937/authorizationexecutewithprivileges-is-deprecated). I'm solving this problem right now too. I don't know if proposed solution is the only right. I will update you if I found solution.

Comment: well, AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges works fine, no deprecated warning and other stuff, just this Log message :|

Comment: I have same. But I left it in my app as it is. As long as it is working :)