# MACOSX: how to start daemon which need root privileges from cocoa application

Tags: macos, cocoa, root, daemon, privileges

Conditions are the following: MacOSX 10.7 and Cocoa graphical application written in objective-c.

I am faced the following problem.
I can't start daemon application from /user/bin folder from my Cocoa application.
I know that I should have root privileges to do that.

I have installer, not *.pkg but manually written installer application. I need to start my daemons after installation process is finished.
How can I increase my privileges level in objective-c application?

I have this code.
But AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges call is deprecated.

We should not use it.

```
AuthorizationItem authItem      = { kSMRightModifySystemDaemons, 0, NULL, 0 };
AuthorizationRights authRights  = { 1, &authItem };
AuthorizationFlags flags        = kAuthorizationFlagDefaults |
                                  kAuthorizationFlagInteractionAllowed |
                                  kAuthorizationFlagPreAuthorize |
                                  kAuthorizationFlagExtendRights;

AuthorizationRef authRef = NULL;

OSStatus status = AuthorizationCreate(&authRights,
kAuthorizationEmptyEnvironment, flags, &authRef);

status = AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges(authorizationRef, tool, kAuthorizationFlagDefaults, args, &pipe);
```

The second way is to use privileged helper. 
This way looks very complicated for my case.
I just need to start daemons after install.

Of cource I can ask user to restart mac. But i would like to avoid it.

Other possibility is SUID bit on the daemon executable file.
But it is not secure i think.

My question is:
Is there other simpler way to do it?

Comment: Are you asking admin password at the time of installation?

Comment: I can ask for password. But AuthorizationCreate and AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges are deprecated. I am using SDK 10.8 and i have compilator warnings about it.

Comment: Have you read this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841937/authorizationexecutewithprivileges-is-deprecated Provides a hacky-tacky solution :)

Comment: .. not the first answer, but from the 2nd onwards, since you don't want helper tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there may be an answer here.

You need to:

1. Create a shell script with your operations.
2. Create an apple script `NSString` in which you request the shell script to be executed `with administrator privilege`.
3. Create an instance of `NSAppleScript` and execute the apple script.

Here are more details:

[AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841937/authorizationexecutewithprivileges-is-deprecated)

Comment: Thank you!   Yes, NSAppleScript  method works without privileged helper.   But you need to enter user password every time you run this script.     Actually I did it with privileged helper.

Comment: Well, it is either that or the privileged helper... You can't have everything... sorry. Isabel