# NSTimer, NSRunloop and deep sleeping mac

Tags: objective-c, macos, nstimer, sleep, nsrunloop

I'm programming an app in objective-c on mac and I need some help. Each day, at 23:59, my app is calling a method to generate a report with

```
NSTimer *timer = [[NSTimer alloc]
                  initWithFireDate:endOfTheDay
                  interval:0.0
                  target:self
                  selector:@selector(endDay)
                  userInfo:nil
                  repeats:NO];

[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

which is working as expected unless the computer is in deep sleep mode. The thing is : I need the timer to call the method at this exact moment of the day even if it is in sleep mode. I'd like not to have to prevent sleep. Can you help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I actually did, is create a pmset event with my arguments and running it as root with an AppleScript line something like this :

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents *currentComponents = [cal components: NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:currentDate];
NSDate *lastDay = [cal dateFromComponents:currentComponents];
NSDateComponents *aDay = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
aDay.day = 1;
NSDate *tonight = [cal dateByAddingComponents:aDay toDate:lastMidnight options:0];

NSString *command = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"pmset schedule wake %@, tonight]
NSString *scriptLine= @"[NSString stringWithFormat:@"do shell script \"%@\" with administrator privileges, command]"

NSAppleScript *myScript = [[NSAppleScript new] initWithSource:scriptLine];
NSAppleEventDescriptor *res = [myScript executeAndReturnError:&errorInfo];
```

Based on
[AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841937/authorizationexecutewithprivileges-is-deprecated) and

Answer (score 3):

Check out IOPMSchedulePowerEvent:

```
 IOReturn IOPMSchedulePowerEvent(
   CFDateRef time_to_wake,
   CFStringRef my_id,
   CFStringRef type);
```

Note that this must be called from root.