# sudo chmod command from cocoa

Tags: cocoa, popen, sudo, nstask

I would like to the run the following command from my Cocoa project. (hides the spotlight icon)

```
sudo chmod 600 /System/Library/CoreServices/Search.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Search
```

I have found two ways how to call the command and get the following output

1) Using NSTask

```
NSTask *writeTask = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[writeTask setLaunchPath:@"/bin/chmod"];

[writeTask setArguments: @[@"755",@"/System/Library/CoreServices/Search.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Search"]];

[writeTask launch];

>>chmod: Unable to change file mode on /System/Library/CoreServices/Search.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Search: Operation not permitted
```

2) Pipes

```
NSString *command = @"sudo chmod 755/System/Library/CoreServices/Search.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Search";
fp = popen([command UTF8String], "r");

>>sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

I have not found a way how to run any of these in super user mode. How can I prompt the user to enter his password and eventually run this command with the required privileges?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges is deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841937/authorizationexecutewithprivileges-is-deprecated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the below apple script using `Apple Script Editor` and save it in a `.scpt` file.

```
do shell script "sudo chmod 600 /System/Library/CoreServices/Search.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Search" with administrator privileges
```

Now add this file to your bundle.

Then to call this script from your program use the following code:

```
- (void) runEmbeddedScriptFile: (NSString*)fileName
{
    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"scpt"];
    NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSDictionary* errors = [NSDictionary dictionary];
    NSAppleScript* appleScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&errors];
   [appleScript executeAndReturnError:nil];
   [appleScript release];
}
```

This will prompt the password request from user.

Answer (score 2):

Prior to 10.7 you could use `AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges()` to execute tasks with privileges. However, this has been deprecated in 10.7 and Apple recommends using the `ServiceManagement` framework to perform privileged tasks.

> SMJobBless demonstrates how to securely install a helper tool that
>   performs a  privileged operation and how to associate the tool with an
>   application that invokes  it.
>
> SMJobBless uses ServiceManagement.framework that was introduced in Mac
>   OS X v10.6  Snow Leopard.
>
> As of Snow Leopard, this is the preferred method of managing privilege
>   escalation on  Mac OS X and should be used instead of earlier
>   approaches such as  BetterAuthorizationSample or directly calling
>   AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges.

Apple's [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SMJobBless/Introduction/Intro.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Authorization Services](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/03authtasks/authtasks.html) to get the root privileges and then use chmod() from sys/stat.h