# How can I gain sudo/admin privileges in C#? Specifically Mono

Tags: c#, .net, macos, mono, sudo

I'm currently working on a desktop application that runs both on Windows and Mac and needs to request sudo access on Mac in order to install and trust a certificate in the users's keychain, I was planning on displaying a window with a textbox that would request the password but this doesn't look like a clean way to do it. I only require to do that once, not everytime the app runs.

The app has been developed using C# and would require sudo in order to execute a console command using Process.Start(...)

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Can't you just run the "sudo" command and pass it the path to the exe as a parameter?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20061526/sudo-chmod-command-from-cocoa

Comment: I want to avoid calling the command directly with sudo but rather have the OS prompt the user for the sudo password when required, like when you're running an installer.