# How to delete system domain file(s) on OS X using Swift 2?

Tags: swift, macos, swift2

For a open source project we want to create a OS X Uninstaller, which should be able to delete *user* and *system domain* files. The goal is to write the Uninstaller in Swift only.

During my research I found examples using `NSTask` to send a `rm` command,
or others recommend using `SMJobBless` and a `HelperTool` for authentication. Both seems for me not the right way. I'm new to the OS X development, so it's hard for me to say which is the right way to achive the task.

I'm looking for an example in Swift 2 which allows user to authenticate and delete *user* and *system domain* files. If any one colud help me, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: i suggest the [Authorization Service Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000995-CH204-TP1). Also, be aware if El Capitan's rootless mode: you can't delete certain system files even if the users have allowed you root access

Comment: Thanks, I will read the guide and try it. Any practical examples are still welcome.

Answer (score 1):

After a couple hours playing around with `SecurityFoundation`, I found it to be too complex for my taste. Plus, the documentation is outdated. Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841937/authorizationexecutewithprivileges-is-deprecated). You can do it via AppleScript.

You need to divide your uninstaller into 2 parts: a default target 
to delete user files and a *helper* to delete system files (with escalated privileges of course).

---

### Option 1

You can write that helper as a shell script and include that as a resource:

File `delete_system_file.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f /usr/local/dummy.txt
```

In your app:

```
let helper = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("delete_system_file", ofType: "sh")!
let script = "do shell script \"\(helper)\" with administrator privileges"

if let appleScript = NSAppleScript(source: script) {
    var error: NSDictionary? = nil

    appleScript.executeAndReturnError(&error)
    if error != nil {
        print(error!)
    } else {
        print("Deleted /usr/local/dummy.txt")
    }
} else {
    print("Cannot create the AppleScript object")
}
```

---

### Option 2

You can do this entirely in Swift by adding a new target to your project. Assuming your first target is called `MyUninstaller`.

#### Add a new target

1. Click `File > New > Target...`
2. Under OS X, select `Application > Command Line Tool`
3. Give your new target a name, say `DeleteSystemFile`

In the **Project Navigator** on the left, expand the `DeleteSystemFile` group and click on the `main.swift` file. To delete the `dummy.txt` file:

```
do {
    try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath("/usr/local/dummy.txt")
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

#### Back to the first target

Now go back to the first target (`MyUninstaller`) and add `DeleteSystemFile` as a Target Dependancy.

[image]

You can run the second target with escalated privileges by calling it through AppleScript:

```
let helper = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForAuxiliaryExecutable("DeleteSystemFile")!
let script = "do shell script \"\(helper)\" with administrator privileges"

if let appleScript = NSAppleScript(source: script) {
    var error: NSDictionary? = nil

    appleScript.executeAndReturnError(&error)
    if error != nil {
        print(error!)
    } else {
        print("Deleted /usr/local/dummy.txt")
    }
} else {
    print("Cannot create the AppleScript object")
}
```

---

### Option 3

Use `SMJobBless`, which is the Apple's recommended way of running privileged helper:

```
import SecurityFoundation
import ServiceManagement

// 1. Obtain an Authorization Reference
// You can do this at the beginning of the app. It has no extra rights until later
var authRef: AuthorizationRef = nil

let status = AuthorizationCreate(nil, nil, [.Defaults], &authRef)

// There's really no reason for this to fail, but we should check or completeness
guard status == errAuthorizationSuccess else {
    fatalError("Cannot create AuthorizationRef: \(status)")
}

// 2. Ask user for admin privilege
var authItem = AuthorizationItem(name: kSMRightBlessPrivilegedHelper, valueLength: 0, value: nil, flags: 0)
var authRights = AuthorizationRights(count: 1, items: &authItem)
let flags: AuthorizationFlags = [.Defaults, .InteractionAllowed, .ExtendRights]

let status2 = AuthorizationCopyRights(authRef, &authRights, nil, flags, nil)
if status2 != errAuthorizationSuccess {
    // Can't obtain admin privilege, handle error
    print("Cannot obtain admin privilege")
}

// 3. Run the privileged helper
// This label must be globally unique and matches the product name of your helper
let label = "com.myCompany.myApp.myAppPrivilgedHelper"
var error: CFError? = nil

let result = withUnsafeMutablePointer(&error) {
    SMJobBless(kSMDomainSystemLaunchd, label, authRef, UnsafeMutablePointer($0))
}

if !result {
    print(error!)
}

// 4. Release the Authorization Reference
AuthorizationFree(authRef, [.Defaults])
```

This involves some setup, which you can read about in the documentation for [`SMJobBless`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ServiceManagement/Reference/ServiceManagement_header_reference/#//apple_ref/c/func/SMJobBless). There's also a [sample project in ObjC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/SMJobBless/Introduction/Intro.html).

Disclaimer: I could not test this all the way as I don't have a personal signing key. I could do away with section 2 from above, but included it here for completeness--that's how the sample project does it.

Comment: Thank you for your effort! I had already tested this method successfuly, but forget to mention it. Sorry for that.

My co-developers mentioned that there might be some limitations using this approach within an signed app. We would also like to create a 'custom uninstaller', so the user can select the components he wants to uninstall. I was thinking more of a combination of using `AuthorizationRights / AuthorizationCopyRights` and the `NSFileManager` to delete the files. Do you know if that is even possible?

Comment: If you have a signing certificate, you can use `SMJobBless`, which is the Apple-blessed way to do this. See Option 3 in my edited answer.