# Run func with root privileges in Swift and Cocoa

Tags: swift, cocoa, root

A specific func in my Swift application need root privileges.
I was wondering if there is a way to gain root access at start of this func to run the following code with this privileges.
Until now I only found a way to gain root access and then run a separate executable which I don't need and which wouldn't work for me.

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: Do you need actual `root` privilege or just [administrator permission](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841937/authorizationexecutewithprivileges-is-deprecated/15248621)?

Comment: I need root privilege for direct hardware access

Comment: For security reasons *run a separate executable* (process) is the recommended way.