# How to enable Touch ID in prompt for password using Applescript in Objective C

Tags: macos, applescript, macos-big-sur, touch-id

I am using a [solution from @CarlosP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15248621/1943799) in my objective C app to execute a script as administrator.

Link is above but basically it's doing this:

```
NSDictionary *errorInfo = [NSDictionary new];
NSString *script =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"do shell script \"%@\" with administrator privileges", fullScript];

NSAppleScript *appleScript = [[NSAppleScript new] initWithSource:script];
NSAppleEventDescriptor * eventResult = [appleScript executeAndReturnError:&errorInfo];
```

It works great, but it doesn't enable/allow Touch ID. Is there a way for me to do that within the scope of `NSAppleScript`?

Comment: There's no reference in the script to TouchID.  A script can't perform operations that it isn't told to.  All this script is doing is instantiating an `NSAppleScript` process in which it uses an AppleScript command to then instantiate a shell process to run the contents of whatever `fullScript` is meant to be.  Did you forget to include the `fullScript` ?  The use of AppleScript here seems unnecessary. If you're running a shell script, you can use `NSTask`.

Comment: `with administrator privileges` invokes a popup asking for admin password. What I'm curious about is how to enable touch ID in that popup. Yes, `fullScript` is just a shell script I've got that needs admin. The contents of the shell script I felt are irrelevent.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable Touch ID authorization for sudo. Check details [here](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2017/11/17/enabling-touch-id-authorization-for-sudo-on-macos-high-sierra/) and [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/259093/can-touch-id-for-the-mac-touch-bar-authenticate-sudo-users-and-admin-privileges).

Add `auth sufficient pam_tid.so` to `/etc/pam.d/sudo` file. In you Applescript
remove `with administrator privileges` and use `sudo` in your shell script.

Comment: Hmm. That might work but I guess I wasn't explicit enough in my question. I want to enable touch ID for software I'm handing to clients, not just my own machine.

Comment: Yes, you're write. The solution will not work for the software.