# how to programmatically edit /etc/hosts file on osx

Tags: objective-c, linux, macos

i want to **restrict**  some **website** for getting open on osx. I can do it through terminal commands as:

```
sudo /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit /etc/hosts
```

then we can easly edit and save this file.just we can write local ip and website name to be restrict this website as 192.0.0.1 www.youtube.com.
I want to do it programmatically, i tried as follows:

`system("echo \"192.0.0.1 www.facebook.com\" >> /etc/hosts");`
this application having root privileges still it is not able to append it and displaying **permission denied** message.
can any one tell me what is the problem, or is there any other way to edit this file /etc/hosts

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

With Apple Script you can do it like this.

```
do shell script "echo '192.0.0.1 www.facebook.com' >> /etc/hosts" with administrator privileges
```

From Objective-C you should use `NSTask` to run shell commands. See [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050687/how-to-use-nstask-as-root) [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541654/how-to-give-permission-using-nstask-objective-c) answers.

Instead of using a shell script, you could also natively write to the file using `NSFileHandle`.
To know all the possibilities check out [Apple's Authorization Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/authorization_concepts/01introduction/introduction.html)

Comment: The `sudo` in this command is pointless. It applies to the left-hand side of the redirect (running the `echo`, which needs no elevated privileges) only.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I've removed the incorrect "sudo" from orkoden's answer.